# Zero-width borders for browser windows in XMonad

Tags: border, window-managers, xmonad

I'm new to `XMonad`. I'd like to have 1px borders for all windows (so I can tell which one is active), except for the browser. In a conventional window manager, I typically have one maximized web browser window in a designated workspace. I'm very used to bringing the mouse cursor all the way to the top edge of the screen to select browser tabs. But if I have 1px border around the browser window, if I slide the mouse all the way to the top it ends up over this border pixel and cannot select the tabs.

Is there a way to define different rules for specific windows regarding border width, or any other such properties?

Alternatively, is there a way to not have a border around any window, if it's the only one on the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of it is possible.

Import xmonad-contrib's [NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) Layout Extension using

```
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
```

Then, in your `manageHook` you can use `hasBorder` with conditions like checking the program's `className` (you may want to use XOrg's Property displayer `xprop` to find out your browser's actual `className`)

```
className =? "firefox" --> hasBorder False
```

Alternatively, you can launch your browser within a given layout and modify that layout in your layoutHook definition to not show borders at all using `noBorders`, or to remove them only in given one-window or fullsize-floating scenarios using `smartBorders`

```
noBorders Full ||| smartBorders Tall ||| ...
```

Comment: Does `className =? "firefox" --> hasBorder False` alone solve the problem? I tried but it didn't work. When I read the source code, I find the `hasBorder` function only broadcast the `HasBorder` message---some code should handle the message and do set the border as 0 width. I assume I need to have `noBorders` or `smartBorders` or `lessBorders` to handle the message. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your layout with one of those. Any will do but you would hardly see the effect with `noBorders` as then all other windows would lose their borders too.