# Config No Border For Specific Windows in Xmonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

### The Goal

Set no border for specific windows in Xmonad.

Concrete example: I'd like `firefox` and `feh` *always* have no border. I want to set this not only for specific layout (e.g., single window) or specific window mode like float.

### Attempt A

The most straight forward idea I have is to add a line in `manageHook`, which supposes to handle window creation. So I put a line in my customized `ManageHook`:

```
className =? "firefox" --> ask >>= \w -> liftX $ withDisplay $ \d -> io $ setWindowBorderWidth d w 0 >> idHook
```

It compiles, but unfortunately nothing happens when I start `firefox`.

Then I try to debug it:

1. Tested the following and it works (new firefox window is floated), which indicates my customized `ManageHook` works, and my logic (modify the window followed by `idHook`) should be OK.

```
className =? "firefox" --> ask >>= liftX . float >> idHook
```

2. Tested `setWindowBorderWidth` function by trying `toggleBorder` in [XMonad.Actions.NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Actions-NoBorders.html). `toggleBorder` does something similarly calling `setWindowBorderWidth`. I used a key binding to invoke `toggleBorder` and it works. So `setWindowBorderWidth` works well during a Xmonad session after the window is created.
3. Tested the following (found it [here](https://xmonad.haskell.narkive.com/130DKJDZ/how-to-make-a-window-floating-above-all-the-other-windows-and-border-less)) but it doesn't work, same as my code (Attempt A).

```
className =? "firefox" --> ask >>= liftX . toggleBorder >> idHook
```

### Attempt B

I find the `hasBorder` function in [XMonad.Layout.NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214309/zero-width-borders-for-browser-windows-in-xmonad/69346065#69346065), but I did not succeed.

If I only put `className =? "firefox" --> hasBorder False` in `ManageHook` but does not use `layoutHook`, nothing happens. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/blob/master/XMonad/Layout/NoBorders.hs) of `hasBorder` and found it only broadcast a message but not set the border. I think I may need to invoke a `layoutHook` from `XMonad.Layout.NoBorders` to really set the border but I am not sure which one I should use. And I am also not sure if I need to specify any layout to use `XMonad.Layout.NoBorders`.

### Questions

1. Does Xmonad set border after `ManageHook` so my code in Attempt A is nullified?
2. If Q1 is true, does it mean I can only set no border at `LayoutHook` (likely using `XMonad.Layout.NoBorders`) when the window is drawn on the screen?
3. If Q2 is true, do I need to specify a layout and which `layoutHook` I can use?

Comment: I don't use xmonad but I know a little bit about its architecture: In general a `Layout` or a `LayoutModifier` implements the message handleing, so if your layouts don't implement the `HasBorder` message, it won't do anything. Of course, `XMonad.Layout.NoBorders` provides a modifier which can handle the `HasBorder` message: `ConfigurableBorder`. The way to build It should be something like `lessBorders Never Tall` or in general `lessBorders <Ambiguity> <Layout>`. Again, I haven't tried any of this but try to modify a layout with `lessBorders` and then call the manageHook `hasBorder False`

Comment: Thank you, @lsmor ! This works to some extent as I mentioned in pmf's answer. However, this triggers a strange "jump" behavior when switching between workspaces. Still wondering what is the procedure of border drawing at different stages in Xmonad.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with attempt B:

Import the [NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) module from xmonad-contrib:

```hs
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
```

Define your constraints in your manageHook:

```hs
className =? "feh"     --> hasBorder False
className =? "firefox" --> hasBorder False
```

And apply one of the module's layout modifiers, e.g. `smartBorders` to **all** of your layouts at once:

```hs
layoutHook = smartBorders $ Full ||| ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) [] ||| ...
```

Note: This will only affect windows created **after** recompiling and restarting XMonad. Already existing instances of firefox and feh would still have their borders until closed and restarted.

Comment: Thank you, pmf! This works, but it has two unintended effects:
1. Automatic using `smartBorders` -- any windows will have no border if it is the only window on screen (I think this is a good side-effect).
2. The border of no-border window looks automatically drawn and removed when switching between workspaces, which leads to a "jump" of window when switching, described here (not sure if this is a bug): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498979/remove-border-from-fullscreen-floating-windows-only-xmonad-configuration

Comment: Regarding #1: I agree that using `smartBorders` might be inconvenient under certain circumstances. You should then define your own `Ambiguity` and use `lessBorders` with it instead. Eventually, `smartBorders` is also just calling `lessBorders Never` (see the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/src/XMonad.Layout.NoBorders.html#smartBorders)).

Comment: Regarding #2: I have noticed a similar, maybe related issue with "jumping" windows due to first-drawn-then-instantly-removed-again borders when switching windows using the Full layout and with at least one window affected by some border elimination feature. I'm inclined to consider this a bug, but as it's hardly noticeable it doesn't really bother me, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the answers to my questions.

**Does Xmonad set border after ManageHook so my code in Attempt A is nullified?**

Yes.

Looks like xmonad window init logic is in [XMonad/Operations.hs](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs). When a window is created, the function [manage()](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs#L88) is called. The last three lines of the function:

1. load `ManageHook`,
2. apply `ManageHook` with `runQuery()`,
3. run the [windows()](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs#L141) function, which [loads border information from config](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs#L147) and applies [setInitialProperties()](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs#L281) function to [set borders according to the border config](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs#L149).

The last step `setInitialProperties()` calls `setWindowBorderWidth()` with border width loaded from config, which nullifies my `setWindowBorderWidth()` as a `ManageHook` step.

If I do not change this logic in [XMonad/Operations.hs](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Operations.hs), it looks like I can only go with Attempt B. However, I really find the [windows *jumping* issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498979/remove-border-from-fullscreen-floating-windows-only-xmonad-configuration) annoying. This does not only occur in `Full` layout, I am using `Tall` with a single window. When I switch between two workspaces, both of which have a single window with no border, I see this *jumping*. The visual effect affects all pixels on screen since it needs to scale the entire window.

***If Q1 is true, does it mean I can only set no border at LayoutHook (likely using XMonad.Layout.NoBorders) when the window is drawn on the screen?***

No. Another possibility besides `LayoutHook` is `logHook`.

***If Q2 is true, do I need to specify a layout and which layoutHook I can use?***

Yes. However, if `logHook` is used, there is no need to overwrite the default layouts.

***Solution***

Let's put up [a new XMonad extension](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/pull/640) to achieve this functionality [that people asked 12 years ago](https://xmonad.haskell.narkive.com/130DKJDZ/how-to-make-a-window-floating-above-all-the-other-windows-and-border-less).